# Date Conversion in .net format "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM"

Tags: .net, date, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a date formatted like

**dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM**

into

**YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffZ**

but had no success.

This is what I've tried:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
string inputDate = "14/02/2008 1:55:11 PM";
DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(inputDate);
DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", enUS, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out newDate);
```

and also:

```
string inputDate = "14/02/2008 1:55:11 PM";
string nw = String.Format("{0:u}", Convert.ToDateTime(inputDate));
```

apart from a few other tricks but nothing seems to work. Please help.

My input string is: `"14/02/2008 1:55:11 PM"`and my output should be `"2008-02-14 1:55:11.000Z"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
string inputdate = "14/02/2008 1:55:11 PM";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(inputdate);
string newDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s.fffZ");
```

I changed "YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffZ" to "yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s.fffZ" because you said:

> my output should be 2008-02-14 **1:55:11**.000Z

Using hh:mm:ss would add leading zeros:

2008-02-14 **01:55:11**.000Z